# Dirrectory name invalid

Tags: windows, python-2.7, directory

The following code gives me the weirdest errors I have seen in a long time. IT gives reference to `/*.*` when I am not using that?
The code:

```
t_src = src.get()
t_dst = dst.get()

print t_src

try:
    for item in os.listdir(t_src):
        print item

        s = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(t_src,item))
        d = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(t_dst, item))

        for filename in os.listdir(s):
            try:
                if os.path.isfile(filename):
                    print filename


                elif os.path.isdir(filename):
                    print "Possible Dirrectory"
                    print filename
                    #shutil.copytree(filename, d)
            except:
                print "Unexpected error:", traceback.format_exc()

except:
    print "Unexpected error:", traceback.format_exc()
```

The error:

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c python CopyDir.py
AS.txt
Unexpected error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CopyDir.py", line 46, in copyFiles
    for filename in os.listdir(s):
WindowsError: [Error 267] The directory name is invalid: 'C:\\Users\\JG
\\Desktop\\Hello World\\AS.txt/*.*'
```

The `src.get()` comes from Tkinter, as I am using a GUI. This is no problem. The `t_src` yields the following example

```
C:/Users/JG/Desktop/Hello World
```

The main goal is to output all of the files that are in the folder and then look for changes between the two, where you have to identical files etc. But as you can see the file structure that it is producing isn't correct.

I am using the Windows Python 2.7.5 along with the text editor VIM (which is brilliant).

Answer (score 0):

The `ITEM` is a file name - giving the file name to the `os.listDir` will result in the error that I am getting. To ratify the problem use the `'os.walk(t_src)'`